# Moodle 2.3: Time Spent value does not get reset for an activity

Tags: android-activity, tracking, moodle

Moodle 2.3: Time Spent value does not get reset for an activity. It always append to the time spent on the activity. Is this default functionality of Moodle or if someone makes a fresh attempt the time spent value should also overwrite the previous value?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Moodle does not, as far as I am aware, have any sort of 'time spent' measurement for activities.

I think your question must either refer to a feature of a specific activity (maybe a 3rd-party plugin you have installed on your site), or to a feature that has been specifically added to your copy of Moodle.

Comment: Moodle does provide facility to track time spent for any activity. Please refer http://docs.moodle.org/19/en/SCORM_reports. My issue is, if user is playing the activity multiple times, then the time spent value is getting appended each time instead of overwriting the previous value.

Comment: So, as I said, this is for a *specific* activity - the SCORM module - not for any activity. It would be clearer if you had mentioned SCORM in the first place.